# Finding a position opposite to a rotated point

Tags: geometry

I have a point that's rotated to a certain angle.
I want to get a point opposite to the direction it's facing.
Also it needs to have a certain distance from it.

I made a little illustration to describe what I want to achieve:

[image]

I have the position and the angle of the red point, but I have no clue how to create the blue point according to it.

Comment: If you know polar coordinates, then this is easily done...

Answer (score 1):

Just find the point that your first arrow points to and invert its coordinates:

[image]

Note that this is for the unit circle, so you also have to scale each component by the radius. This article should be a good read: [Unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#Trigonometric_functions_on_the_unit_circle)

Or more explicitly:

```
P = center + <-distance * cos(angle), -distance * sin(angle)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a point

```
P=(px, py)
```

the point

```
P'=(-px, -py)
```

is the location of P rotated about the origin by 180°.

So, given your Red point

```
D=(dx, dy)
```

and an angle θ and a radius r, the blue point will be at

```
B=(dx-r*cos θ, dy-r*sin θ)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look on this :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

If you are working with x,y position integer. You just have to do :

the rotation matrix multiply by [ x , y]' like show on this page. And your Theta is 180.